# Show/Hide dropdownlist depending of the value selected in other dropdownlist (angular.js)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs

How can I show or hide a dropdownlist depending of the value selected in other dropdownlist?

I'm using C# with AngularJS. I would like to use the capability of Angular to avoid the postback.

I have the following **code**:

```
<div style="float:left;">
            <label>Combo 1:</label><asp:DropDownList ID="cmbCombo1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;" id="divCombo2">
            <label>Combo 2:<asp:DropDownList ID="cmbCombo2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

I have populated the cmb1 in codebehind, so I would like to hide or show the cmb2 depending of the value selected in cmb1.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You need a way to attach the `ngModel` directive to the combo box.  From there, you can do `$watch`, `filter`, etc.  The best solution depends on the context of what the objects used to populate each box looks like.

Comment: Any example of how to do it?